# Why must integral manifolds be immersed submanifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Given a manifold $M$ and a distribution $D \subset TM$, an integral manifold of $D$ is defined as a nonempty immersed submanifold $N \subset M$ such that $T_pN = D_p$ for all $p \in N$.

Why are we not able to define an integral manifold as an embedded submanifold? My guess is that embeddings are too strict, but is there an intuitive geometric reason behind this?

Comment: I can't think of a quick reason immediately, but integral manifolds are always weakly embedded in the sense that whenever $S$ is a third manifold and $f\colon S \to M$ is a smooth map whose image is contained in $N$, then $f\colon S \to N$ is smooth. See Chapter 19 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. Some people like to call manifolds with this property "conservative", but that's a terrible name. Anyhow, the point is that this property (whatever you decide to call it) seems to be enough for most applications?

Comment: @IvoTerek So the definition is as it is so that it captures all the applications we would like and less so geometrically motivated?

Comment: Integral submanifolds generalize the notion of integral curves for usual first order ODE $\gamma' = X(\gamma)$ for $X$ a vector field. In general, an integral curve won't be an embedded curve, only immersed (think of $X$ being a constant vector field with irrational slope on the 2-torus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to define integrability of distributions, then you can equivalently use embedded submanifolds. (Indeed, for an immersed submanifold $N\to M$ and $x\in N$ there always is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $N$ which is an embedded submanifold in $M$.) But if you go to the general study of integral submanifolds (usually called the global version of the Frobenius theorem), then embedded submanifolds are too restrictive. What you prove there is the through each point there is a maximal connected (immersed) integral submanifold, called the leaf through $x$. This is not embedded in general, but as stated in the comment of @Ivo_Terk, it can be shown that these leaves are always weakly embedded or so-called initial submanifolds. But this is the result of a theorem (and it is a global condition) and it would be rather strange (and not intuitive) to make this part of the definition.